# How to protect python scripts?

Tags: python

When I prepared to distribute my first python application several years ago, I had to face a problem: how to obfuscate python scripts so no clear code shown to my customer?

Comment: Answers are v old on the other questions: so an update is warranted here.

Answer (score 1):

Now I have one solution

### Build Obfuscated Script

First compile Python script to code object

```
char *filename = "foo.py";
char *source = read_file( filename );
PyCodeObject *co = Py_CompileString( source, "<frozen foo>", Py_file_input );
```

Next change this code object as the following ways

- Wrap byte code `co_code` within a `try...finally` block

  wrap header:

  ```
      LOAD_GLOBALS    N (__armor_enter__)     N = length of co_consts
      CALL_FUNCTION   0
      POP_TOP
      SETUP_FINALLY   X (jump to wrap footer) X = size of original byte code
  ```

  changed original byte code:

  ```
      Increase oparg of each absolute jump instruction by the size of wrap header

      Obfuscate original byte code

      ...
  ```

  wrap footer:

  ```
      LOAD_GLOBALS    N + 1 (__armor_exit__)
      CALL_FUNCTION   0
      POP_TOP
      END_FINALLY
  ```
- Append function names `__armor_enter`, `__armor_exit__` to `co_consts`
- Increase `co_stacksize` by 2
- Set CO_OBFUSCAED (0x80000000) flag in `co_flags`
- Change all code objects in the `co_consts` recursively

Then serialize this reformed code object, obfuscate it to protect constants and literal strings

```c
char *string_code = marshal.dumps( co );
char *obfuscated_code = obfuscate_algorithm( string_code  );
```

Finally generate obfuscated script

```c
sprintf( buf, "__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'%s')", obfuscated_code );
save_file( "dist/foo.py", buf );
```

The obfuscated script is a normal Python script, it looks like this

```
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x01\x0a...')
```

### Run Obfuscated Script

In order to run obfuscted script `dist/foo.py` by common Python Interpreter,
there are 3 functions need to be added to module `builtins`: `__pyarmor__`, `__armor_enter__`, `__armor_exit__`

- `__pyarmor__` will be called at first, it will import original module from obfuscated code

  ```c
  static PyObject * 
  __pyarmor__(char *name, char *pathname, unsigned char *obfuscated_code)
  {
      char *string_code = restore_obfuscated_code( obfuscated_code );
      PyCodeObject *co = marshal.loads( string_code );
      return PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx( name, co, pathname );
  }
  ```
- `__armor_enter__` is called as soon as code object is executed

  ```c
  static PyObject * 
  __armor_enter__(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
  {
      // Got code object
      PyFrameObject *frame = PyEval_GetFrame();
      PyCodeObject *f_code = frame->f_code;

      // Increase refcalls of this code object
      // Borrow co_names->ob_refcnt as call counter
      // Generally it will not increased  by Python Interpreter
      PyObject *refcalls = f_code->co_names;
      refcalls->ob_refcnt ++;

      // Restore byte code if it's obfuscated
      if (IS_OBFUSCATED(f_code->co_flags)) {
          restore_byte_code(f_code->co_code);
          clear_obfuscated_flag(f_code);
      }

      Py_RETURN_NONE;
  }
  ```
- `__armor_exit__` is called so long as code object completed execution

  ```c
  static PyObject * 
  __armor_exit__(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
  {
      // Got code object
      PyFrameObject *frame = PyEval_GetFrame();
      PyCodeObject *f_code = frame->f_code;

      // Decrease refcalls of this code object
      PyObject *refcalls = f_code->co_names;
      refcalls->ob_refcnt --;

      // Obfuscate byte code only if this code object isn't used by any function
      // In multi-threads or recursive call, one code object may be referened
      // by many functions at the same time
      if (refcalls->ob_refcnt == 1) {
          obfuscate_byte_code(f_code->co_code);
          set_obfuscated_flag(f_code);
      }

      // Clear f_locals in this frame
      clear_frame_locals(frame);

      Py_RETURN_NONE;
  }
  ```

Interested? Visit https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor